# Django ModelChoseField limited to current logged user

Tags: django

I wrote in `forms.py` this code

`id_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StudentsGroup.objects.filter(id_teacher=1))`

How change `1` to current logged user?

I try do this `User.objects.get(username=request.user.get_username())` but do not work

Comment: Where did you write it? What does "do not work" mean? (btw. `request.user` would be the same as that entire last query)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the current user to the from when you initialize it in the view: `form = MyForm(user=request.user)`, then you can do something like the following in your form:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        groups = StudentsGroup.objects.filter(id_teacher=self.user.pk)
        self.fields['id_group'].queryset = groups
```

Comment: Now i have `KeyError ` `'user'`

Comment: You need to provide `user` as a keyword argument when initializing the form as shown above... Hard to tell where your error is without your actual form/view code...